# Image Slider in GWT

Tags: javascript, jquery, gwt, slideshow, uislider

I'm looking for a simple image slider content with the following features in GWT:

- slide several images from right to left when user clicks on the image
  (selected image should be at the center)
- endless looping (the last image should be followed by the first image
  again)

We tried a lot on web for slider but no result.
any recommendations?

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any native GWT sliders. The easiest way to implement one is probably to use a pre-made Javascript version from, well, pretty much anywhere on the web. You can learn about wrapping Javascript libraries [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html), [here](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/DesigningAPIWrappers) and [here](http://blog.vzv.ca/2011/04/integrating-javascript-libraries-in-gwt.html), and find lots of other resources by searching Google.